# Line integral work-checking

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate $\int_Cy^2dx+z^2dy+ (1-x^2) dz $  where C is the quarter of the circle of radius 1 in the xz-plane with center at the origin in the quadrant $x \ge 0,z \leq 0$, oriented counter-clockwise when viewed from the positive y-axis, that is, looking in the -y direction.

I parameterized the curve and got $r(t) = \langle \cos(t), 0, -\sin(t)\rangle$, $ 0 \leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Plugging this into the integral, I get  $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}0^2(-\sin(t))+(-\sin(t))^2(0)+ (1-\cos^2(t)) (-\cos(t))dt $

Which simplifies to $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos^3(t)-\cos(t)dt $

Solving this integral, I get $\frac{-1}{3}$.

Did I do this problem correctly?

Comment: It seems correct.  you have a typo ( the $0^2$ term) in the last integral.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Fixed.

Comment: This looks like a job for **_Green's Theorem!_**